# control character error when loading facebook 600m NLLB model

Tags: python, torch, huggingface-tokenizers

It happens when i try to load the 600M parameters NLLB model from facebook. Tried to update transformes but it does not seem to be that the issue. Using huggingface. Ideas? Thanks!

Exception: control character (\u0000-\u001F) found while parsing a string at line 694727 column 33
Model: https://huggingface.co/facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M

Tried to update transformes but it does not seem to be that the issue.